# Is there any better approach then K folds and nested K folds?

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting

I am trying to understand what problem is K-folds solving.
It does not seem to be solving data leakage at all, as we are still testing on test data and then taking an average of all test folds and then retune the model.

I can understand that with each model, it is like training on new data set, this seems to be the positive point.

Now, if I understand correctly, nested K folds seems to be solving this data leakage problem. but it is like performing the model tuning K times and coming up with K models. I really dont see much benefit rather then having 5 model and using them on real time.

Now, why cant simply we have alternative approach.
Have K folds, keep 1 fold as only test data.
Use K-1 folds for K fold validation (K-2 for train, 1 fold for CV). Using this way, we evaluate our model on unseen data.

But certainly, there must be some drawbacks with this, I want to understand why this alternative approach is better than K folds and nested K folds.

Answer (score 0):

**K-fold** (and nested K-fold, when also tuning hyper parameters) improve the efficiency of data we have for training and testing.
Imagine that you are using a data set of *n* records and you apply **K-fold**. This will give you effective prediction performance metrics had you trained the model on the whole set as well as tested it on the same set, but, as if they do not overlap. This method achieves it by avoiding the overlap in bits and pieces at the cost of training the model *k* times. To put it in other words, it will give you the same level of prediction performance to another model that you would train on a data set of size *n* and test on another separate non-overlapping data set of the same size, hence require twice the size of dataset used in **K-fold** for the same results.